# Widget is created before it should be used => leads to error

Tags: flutter

I have a custom widget with a futurebuilder which I want to use to load some data.

This is how it looks like:

```
class LoadOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget child;
  LoadOverlay({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadOverlayState createState() => _LoadOverlayState();
}

class _LoadOverlayState extends State<LoadOverlay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Catalog.catalog.loadAsset(), //Here the csvString gets loaded
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return widget.child;
          else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(), //Tells the user that something is loading
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how i use it:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoadOverlay(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(Catalog.catalog.csvString), //This gets created to early
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The Problem is that `Text(Catalog.catalog.csvString)` gets loaded before the futurebuilder executes and because csvString hasn't finished i get an null error. If i put this into the *LoadOverlay* like this

```
if (snapshot.hasData)
    Text(Catalog.catalog.csvString)
```

it works because the code gets only executed after the snapshot has data.

**So how do I pass a Widget to the FutureBuilder that gets called and drawn AFTER the future was executed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution could be to use a `builder` property in your custom widget instead of a `child` property. This would look like:

```
class LoadOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget Function(BuildContext) builder;
  LoadOverlay({Key key, this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadOverlayState createState() => _LoadOverlayState();
}

class _LoadOverlayState extends State<LoadOverlay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Catalog.catalog.loadAsset(), //Here the csvString gets loaded
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return widget.builder(context);
          else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(), //Tells the user that something is loading
              ),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LoadOverlay(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(Catalog.catalog.csvString), //This gets created to early
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This way your code which you inject into the `builder` property gets only executed if the `Future` is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an empty `String` while `csvString` is still `null`.

```
child: Text(Catalog.catalog.csvString ?? ''),
```

**OR**

Assign an empty `String` to `csvString` when it is initialized.

```
String csvString = '';
```